# How to configure spring controller to use different objectMapper for the response (serialization)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I configured my own ObjectMapper for my SpringBoot application, Let say the object mapper is something like below (simplified):

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }
```

Since the `ObjectMapper` is a `singleton`, all my REST Controller use that same ObjectMapper.
But, there is some controller that I want to ignore the null value, but I want to keep the rest of my controller to send the null value response.

Is there a way to configure it? So the best result is I can configure something like this:

- Controller A,B,C -> ObjectMapper X (ignore null value)
- Controller D -> ObjectMapper Y (ignore empty value)
- Default (all other controller) -> ObjectMapper Z (return null value)

Requirement Note:

- **I can't change the POJO since it's autogenerated, and I don't want to update the codegen lib or the mustache template for this.**
- **Specific content negotiation is not an option**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your `ObjectMapper` annotated with `@Primary`
you can configure more `ObjectMapper`s qualified with bean names of your choice.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return objectMapper;
}

@Bean("mySpecialObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper anotherObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            /*  do some other configuration */;
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Then you can refer to them in your controllers like this:

- Just giving `@Autowired` will inject the primary `ObjectMapper`.
- Giving `@Autowired` together with `@Qualifier("anyName")` will inject
  the `ObjectMapper` configured with `@Bean("anyName")`

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mySpecialObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper otherObjectMapper;
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is to make Spring to use the other ObjectMapper depend on the controller. For example, for the `Response` class I used `javax.ws.core.response` and I just need to pass in the model.

But the transform to JSON at the `@Component` (my controller) were made by the primary ObjectMapper since it will use what Spring provide.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just need to use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL). Try to fix it in the response model level.

Comment: Yes it will work, but as I mention in the requirement note, I can't change the POJO model since it's autogenerated.